# dynamic error text in jquery ui error text not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to have error alert using jquery ui, the below code

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "signin.html",
                    type : "post",
                    cache : false,
                    data : "userName=" + $("#userName").val()
                            + '&password=' +                  $("#password").val(),
                    success : function(response) {
                        $('#errorbox').show();
                        $('#message').text(response);

                    },
                    error : function() {
                        alert('Error while response..');
                    }

                });
            });
});

<div class="ui-widget"
        style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 10%; text-align: center;">
        <div id="errorbox" style="display: none; width: 30%"
            class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all">
            <p>
                <span id="message" name="message" class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"/>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the text in the `$('#message').text(response);` is not getting displayed

[image]

i have looked this http://jsfiddle.net/774wH/, but this is static error message. how to achieve the dynamic text with ui alert css style.

Comment: try `alert(response)` or `console.log(response)` to see what it is?

Comment: @WayneWang i am getting alert but not getting displayed in the box !!!!

Comment: do you mean if you add an `alert(response)` before  `$('#message').text(response);`  you can get an alert but the next statement `$('#message').text(response);`  won't get executed?

Comment: yes, I am getting alert , but response text is not adding to the message span element. if I remove the class in  <span> then getting message but without alert icon

Comment: will this work? http://jsfiddle.net/Eupfq/ you might need to play with some css but the text is now displaying

Comment: nope.. i am getting error in reponse

Comment: try again? it might be a jsFiddle error..

Comment: i am getting the text, by putting another span element as you mentioned but it is not aligned properly, i mean the text is below the alert icon , which i dont want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the JSFiddle I have created here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/B7MHy/.

The key to this example is the following style which is applied to the ui-icon-alert class:

```
.ui-icon.ui-icon-alert { 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 45px;
    bottom: 1px;
}
```

The "float:left" style causes the "error" span to flow around the alert icon, hence causing the icon and error message to be rendered side-by-side as opposed to being on top of each other.

Note that I have also tweaked the position of the error icon so that it does not look orphaned from the text.

Comment: i have seen the fiddle, but i need to alert image to align left, but there it is center positioned and messed with the text

Comment: Your question does not indicate how you'd like to see the alert. You just state that the message "is not getting displayed". How can people help you with the styling if your not giving a good description of what you want?

Comment: cool, i have tweaked the left positioning to 10px, and this is what i need. thanks Fresh.

Comment: @pappu_kutty Cool :) I've too have fixed the position in the Fiddle to match what I think you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Your ui-alert-icon class is setting the span to be the size of the warning icon. So you can't see the text you're putting in there.

You're going to have to add another span next to this one, and put your response text inside.

If you want it to be next to it, and not under it, you'll have to use `float: left` on your `span`s

(for some reason I can't access jsFiddle right now, but as soon as it's working again I'll post one.)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing dataType: "html",

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
     <style type="text/css">         
     </style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="userName" value="" />
<input type="text" id="password" value="" />
<button>Submit</button>

<div class="ui-widget"
    style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 10%; text-align: center;">
    <div id="errorbox" style="display: none; width: 30%"
        class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all">
        <p>
            <span id="message" name="message" class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"/>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("button").click(
                function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "signin.html",
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: "html",
                        cache: false,
                        data: "userName=" + $("#userName").val()
                                + '&password=' + $("#password").val(),
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#errorbox').show();
                            $('#message').text(response);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Error while response..');
                        }

                    });
                });
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: kundan, this is part of html, it is body and section of layout jsp which has doctype

Comment: sorry unable to open jsfiddle.net/774wH/ I think not working this time

Answer (score 0):

You can not overwrite the span value which has class `ui-icon ui-icon-alert` because it is icon(background-image),
so just create another element with `id` then append your value to that id it works good

HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
<p>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
<strong id="test"></strong>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "signin.html",
                    type : "post",
                    cache : false,
                    data : "userName=" + $("#userName").val()
                            + '&password=' +                  $("#password").val(),
                    success : function(response) {
                        $('#errorbox').show();
                        $('#test').text(response);

                    },
                    error : function() {
                        alert('Error while response..');
                    }

                });
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with html:

```
<span id="message" name="message" class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"/>
```

replace:

```
<span id="message" name="message" class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>
```

hope it will fix porblem